# How to show who has visited a User's profile in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, associations, model-associations

Got a quick question on setting up how to show who has visited a user's profile on my app using rails? I was following the accepted answer on this question -  [How to show who has visited your profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317985/how-to-show-who-has-visited-your-profile) but ran into an error that's got me a bit confused. I have listed the error that I receive and my relevant code below:

Two Errors appearing in my users controller

Error1: undefined method `visits' for nil:NilClass
Error2: can't write unknown attribute`visitor_id` >> Whenever I visit a user's profile

**User controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :share, :follow]
before_action :create_visit

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@visitprofiles = current_user.visitors.where('created_at > ?', 1.month.ago)
end
private

def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])  
end

def create_visit
@user.visits.create(visitor: current_user)
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]




has_many :visits
has_many :visitors, through: :visits
```

**Visit.rb**

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :visitor, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'visitor_id'
end
```

Comment: you should probably use `before_action :create_visit, only: [:show]` otherwise the number will be too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `@user` is `nil`.

You have `before_action :set_user`, but it's not invoked before `create_user`.

In your `create_user`, your `@user` is not set, therefore, it's nil.

**Two gems for debugging**

You should be shown where the code is breaking. [Better errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) and [Binding or callers](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller) are two gems that I found useful for fast debugging Rails app.

***Another issue with your code***

You `set_user` brefore `show`, and you have the exact same logic to look for a user in your `show` method. This is not DRY.

Comment: Edmond thank you so much for your response, Im following you a little bit, how would I go about resolving it. Would i need to change the user.rb ?

Comment: @Omar you need to `set_user` before you `create_visit`. simply add `create_visit` to your `only:` array in `before_action :set_user`.

Comment: Edmund got it so it doesn't give me an error any longer as I did the following like you suggest: ``before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :share, :follow, :create_visit]``. Now on my views to count the number of visitors. Should I do the following in controller - ``@visitprofiles = current_user.visitors.where('created_at > ?', 1.month.ago)`` and in my views simple do ``<%= @visitprofiles.count %>``?

Comment: I get this error when I follow that though >> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: visits.user_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "visits" ON "users"."id" = "visits"."visitor_id" WHERE "visits"."user_id" = ? AND (created_at > '2016-12-30 21:01:20.902216')

Comment: @Omar looks like your `visits` table doesn't have a `user_id` column

Comment: Edmund thank you so much so I did this migration to compensate as you suggestion for a user_id column ``rails g migration AddUserRefToVisits user_id:integer`` however I still get this error SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "visits" ON "users"."id" = "visits"."visitor_id" WHERE "visits"."user_id" = ? AND (created_at > '2016-12-30 22:13:28.581400')

Comment: @Omar that's because both your `visits` and `users` table have `created_at` column. you need to specify which one should be used by doing something like this `users.created_at > ...`

Comment: thank you so much mate!! Accepted your answer  - just want to finalize this error - I followed your suggestion and placed ``@visitprofiles = @user.visitors.where('users.created_at > ?', 1.month.ago)`` but got this SQL error that I think might be due to my model association btw visit and user. Any help on how I can fix this would be amazing SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: visits.visitor_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "visits" ON "users"."id" = "visits"."visitor_id" WHERE "visits"."user_id" = ? AND (users.created_at > '2016-12-31 17:53:08.952545')

Comment: @Omar looks like you don't have `visitor_id` column in your `visits` table? you need both `user_id` and `visitor_id`

Comment: thanks mate - that works amazing! However, the number is always 0 regardless of how many times I look at my profile from another user's account - I've tried solving it in my own but its stays as 0 regardless?

Comment: @Omar I assume you should be counting `visits` instead of `visitors`? and have you validate if `visits` are being created?